# temp folder in Macos under root?

Tags: mac-osx, scripting, root

I'm eriting a MacOS script that need to run under admin rights (under 'sudo'). Script needs a temp folder in order to keep some temp files. Unfortunately, there is no 'TMPDIR' under root! If i run 'env' i see TMPDIR with a nice temp path. If i run 'sudo env' i don't see TMPDIR :(. Is it any way to obtain correct "temp folder" path under root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a $TMPDIR, use it. Otherwise use /tmp (it should exist on Mac too).

Comment: Using /tmp looks fine for me. Is it any official BSD documentation that instructs to use it under root account, or is it a common knowledge?

Comment: /tmp is just the standard location for temporary files, as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 2):

In general, you're supposed to create temp files using the library-provided functions and use the filenames and/or handles provided. On mac, the mktemp(1) command with the "-d" option should do what you want.

> NAME
>        mktemp -- make temporary filename (unique)
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        mktemp [-dqtu] [-p directory] [template]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The mktemp utility takes the given filename template and overwrites
>   a
>        portion of it to create a unique filename.  The template may be any
>   file-
>        name with some number of `Xs' appended to it, for example
>        /tmp/tfile.XXXXXXXXXX.  If no template is specified a default of
>        tmp.XXXXXXXXXX is used and the -t flag is implied (see below).